# why my nuget browser window in visual studio like this?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019

Some of the nuget packages I'm using in a c# project were not installed on this machine. I clicked on "find this namespace on nuget.org ..." and Visual Studio opens "Nuget Browser" to lookup nuget for this namespace. However, the browser window is transparent over my code and no suggestion are prompted!

[image: sual]

Comment: I'm having an hard time understanding what the question is: the issue is that the nuget browser bar in light blue is transparent instead of solid?

Comment: What happens if you grab the title bar of the nuget browser and try to drag it someplace else, or double click on it?  It might be stuck in some kind of odd docked state.

Comment: @DaemonPainter sorry , no. my nuget browser window must be show suggested nuget packages but not working , and show me transparent window that show me my code lines below

Comment: @BradleyUffner i try it , but not working

Comment: @Madadinoei, did you use resharper extension with nuget brower window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite strange and in my side, it will not cover the code editor in a transparent manner.

[image]

[image]

So please try the following steps:

**Suggestion**

**1)** disable any third party extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions** except **Resharper** to check to see if other vs extensions are interfering with ReSharper.

**2)** Close VS, delete all component cache files under any path `C:\Users\xxx(current user )\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxxx\ComponentModelCache`

**3)** reset all VS settings under **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset All Settings**

and

also try to reset Resharper Settings by **Extensions**-->**Resharper**-->**Manage Options**-->**Reset All Settings**

**4)** run `devenv /ResetSkipPkgs` under Developer Command Prompt for VS2019 to start your VS to test it.

**5)** or try to restart **Resharper** Extensions, first disable it and then close VS, then restart VS to enable the extension.

**6)** if there is any update for VS or Resharper, please update them.